# How do I keep Windows (Vista) boot manager from automatically coming up when booting up computer

Tags: windows-vista

I am trying to keep the boot manager from automatically coming up when booting up my Windows Vista computer. I also want to know why the boot manager is coming up.

I have also been having other problems that mite be related. After restarting a few times my USB mouse did not work. After unplugging and plugging back in my mouse worked. But after restarting a few more times each time looking at the options when I press F8, my non USB keyboard stopped working. Unplugging and plugging back did not help. I am now using a USB keyboard.

This computer has not been in use for at least 6 months. When we did finally turn it on it started doing some kind of a repair. When it finished it said that it failed. We restarted and it seemed to work.

For the moment the only problems I have is the non USB keyboard not working (maybe a hardware problem) and the boot manager coming up.

We have been doing a lot of moving. Maybe the computer was damaged.

Comment: I think you'll do better posting your question on SuperUser.com.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the boot manager coming up"? What options are being displayed by the boot manager? Is it prompting you to go into safe mode, or displaying multiple OSes, or what?

Comment: First off the problem has stopped occurring. Secondly when I turned on the computer instead of booting up normally the boot manager appeared. And There was only one OS to choose from.

Comment: If I remember right it was prompting me to go into safe mode. And again, if I remember right when I selected safe mode, windows would run normally until I restarted. Then the boot manager would appear again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "boot manager", do you mean the Windows Error Recovery/"Windows did not shut down successfully" screen? If so, it means, well, that Windows did not shutdown correctly. If it was whilst it was applying a series of updates, that could indicate it was being turned off at the mains before the installation of patches on shutdown (can take a while when patching sometimes) or otherwise forcibly shutdown (ie holding the power swtich or pulling the power lead).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is no longer occurring. I still don't know why it occurred but maybe a windows update fixed it. The computer has been unplugged for a long time and on the first few boots there was windows update after windows update.